# Amplification of Bolometer

Tags: voltage, amplifier, voltage-amplification

How would one measure the microvolts change in a 50kΩ Bolometer, as a result of the radiation impinging on it?

Comment: For anyone wondering: "A bolometer is a device for measuring the power of incident electromagnetic radiation via the heating of a material with a temperature-dependent electrical resistance. It was invented in 1878 by the American astronomer Samuel Pierpont Langley."  [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bolometer).

Comment: define your "emmitor "

Comment: A matched pair in a differential test is used.

Answer (score 2):

You can directly measure the voltage with a 24-bit ADC. If you have ENOB of (say) 20 bits and a full scale range of 600mV your resolution is about 600nV, so you can measure the 129uV to a resolution of about 0.5%.

Chances are your reference divider won't be stable to 1ppm for very long and there are other issues with keeping noise and thermal EMFs in check, but that's the 50,000 ft view. The ADC reference should be ratiometric to the bolometer excitation (ie. dervived from the same reference voltage) so it cancels out, because a 1ppm reference is both very difficult to achieve and unnecessary.

You could also build a full [Wheatstone](https://www.telegraph.co.uk/content/dam/technology/Spark/btconnectingbritain/charles-wheatstone.jpg?imwidth=1400) [bridge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wheatstone_bridge#:%7E:text=A%20Wheatstone%20bridge%20is%20an,which%20includes%20the%20unknown%20component.) with ultra-high precision resistors to buck the voltage from the pair of resistors in the bolometer, then the ADC can measure the difference in voltages, which can be amplified first.

In the case of the [Langley bolometer](https://archive.org/details/bolometerlangley00langrich/mode/2up) both halves of the Wheatstone bridge were part of the construction of the sensor, which is obviously preferable so that various inaccuracies and drifts cancel out.

Comment: Unfortunately, I only have access to 16 Bit ADC. 24 Bit ADC would be too expensive. 
How can I measure the voltage of Bolometer when I use Wheatstone Bridge?

Comment: You need to do a sensitivity analysis and study amplifier datasheets and compare with your requirements. Requirements come first. Actually a 24 bit ADC is considerably cheaper than two Z-foil resistors.